# Jquery Conflict in Joomla

Tags: jquery

I am using a Joomla template and I am having problems with conflicts with Jquery.  When I place a HTML code on my site the slideshow that uses wigitkit goes blank.  I copied the error code I received.  Can anyone provide any suggestion how I can cure the conflict.  I installed the jquery easy plugin but it does not work.

Here is the error message

```
Multiple jQuery Libraries found. Please make sure these don't conflict each other.
/components/com_community/assets/imgareaselect/scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.js
/components/com_community/assets/imgareaselect/scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.min.js
/components/com_community/assets/imgareaselect/scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js
/components/com_community/assets/joms.jquery.js
/components/com_community/assets/joms.jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js
/components/com_community/assets/joms.jquery.mobile-1.4.2.pack.js
/components/com_community/assets/joms.jquery.pack.js
/components/com_community/assets/jquery-1.3.2.pack.js
/components/com_community/assets/jquery-ui-tabs.min.js
/components/com_community/assets/jquery.tablednd_0_5.js
/components/com_community/assets/jquery.tablednd_0_5.pack.js
/components/com_community/assets/multiupload_js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js
/components/com_community/assets/multiupload_js/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js
/components/com_community/assets/tipsy-0.1.7/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js
/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js
/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/js/jquery/jquery-ui-layout.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js
/media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery.nivo.slider.min.js
/plugins/system/jqueryeasy/jquerynoconflict.js
```

Comment: just remove the multiple instances of jQuery so their is only one

Answer (score 0):

Use only one version (Probably latest) of jQuery. and include it at top before including other plugin files.
For example , use this at top of your html page inside head section:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>`
```

Comment: I am not an expert at coding...could you explain where exactly do I place this code?  I am using the admin backend to update site.

Comment: You have to go to the .html file that is causing you the issue. inside  that file look for <html><head> <--- place the above script here ---> </head> <body> </body></html>. Also make sure to remove all the other jquery reference scripts. like the scripts that start with jquery.XXX.js. remove all these types of scripts.

Comment: I search everwhere in my joomla admin page.  I do not see libraries or edit approach to edit codes.  Could you assist?

Comment: No , you have to go to your actual joomla directory. that will be in your C: drive of your hard-disk most probably. navigate to your file path. and  then edit it's source code directly. by opening in any text editor.

Comment: For example. In /media/mod_vt_nivo_slider/js/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
all these are directories and sub directories and at last your jquery.min.js file.
As a whole this gives you the path to this jquery file. Now you need to look for the path of your html file.
When u open your page in browser. look in the URL field, you can get your file path from there.

Comment: I don't have the site on my C:drive.  I used http://www.ourwebsitename.com/home/administrator to access my Joomla template. I appreciate your help Mr. Faizan.  I am a bit over my head with trying to access the source. I am trying to figure out how to integrate this template to dreamweaver so I can easily see all the coding for the site.